# How to link segments with the same type but different flags from different object files (ELF)?

Tags: linker, elf

I'm curious about how does a linker link segments with same type but different flags from different object files. E.g. we now have two ELF object files `foo.o` and `bar.o`, both of which have a `.text` segment (code segment). However, `.text` segment in `foo.o` is write-able while that in `bar.o` is not. In this case, how will the linker link these two segments? How will the linker set the flag of the `.text` segment in the linked file?

Thanks and Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How will the linker set the flag of the .text segment in the linked file?

There is no `.text` segment in the linked file: the `.text` section is put into one of the `LOAD` segments.

The linker can choose what to do.

- it can create multiple `.text` sections with different flags, and put them into multiple `LOAD` segments.
- it can merge all `.text` sections from `foo.o` and `bar.o` into a single `.text` section, and make it writable
- it can fail the link